# Find a next record after disabling a record?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a created a function `changeIp()` to disabled a record and return a new record. As you can see I am using 3 SQL query.

Is there a better way doing to reduce number of SQL queries?

```
function changeIp() {

    // Find 1 record which is not disabled
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM ip WHERE disable = 0 order by id limit 1";
    $qIp = mysql_query($SQL) or die(mysql_error());
    $qrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($qIp);

    // Disable a record
    $id = $qrow['id'];
    $SQL = "UPDATE ip set disable = 1 WHERE id = $id";
    mysql_query($SQL) or die(mysql_error());

    // Return the next record
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM ip WHERE disable = 0 order by id limit 1";
    $qIp = mysql_query($SQL) or die(mysql_error());
    $qrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($qIp);

    return $qrow['ip'];
}
```

Comment: why don't you return 2 rows in the first query, update 1 and return the other ?

Comment: You can use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` in an update query, so the first thing to do, would be to combine the first 2 queries into 1.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "mysqli" or php, but that is a separate matter from your question.

Your queries are fine.  You can't really do an `update` and `select` in a single statement.  You can improve performance with an index on `ip(id, disable)`.  And, an index on `ip(disable, id)` might also be beneficial, depending on a number of factors.